# vuejs2 - How to keep checked radios on dynamically created row

Tags: arrays, forms, vuejs2, radio-button

Loosing the `checked` `radio` on a dynamically created row with radios.
How to map it to the row where it got created on/belongs to.

This is a demo [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/samimi_it/18w2u35z/42/)

It does not remain `checked` on and as per the clicked `row/index`. Jumps to the next `checked` `radio` row.

Comment: change radio button tag's name attribute like:  <input type="radio" :name="'op'+rowNum"...

Answer (score 0):

You should assign a "name" on the options that is unique per row. (I think that's what you want, at least)

You can create a data model that is actually storing the value by using v-model (which just binds the value to the data model), and then assign the selectable values using the row model.

That way when you remove a row, you're effectively removing the data associated it rather than just "shifting down" the DOM, which is probably why you're getting the results you're getting.

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   isSelected: false,
    selected: '',
    option: '',
  rows: [
    {
     options:[
       {name:'Option 1',value:'opt1'},
        {name:'Option 2',value:'opt2'},
        {name:'Option 3',value:'opt3'},
        {name:'Option 4',value:'opt4'},
        {name:'Option 5',value:'opt5'}
      ],
      value:''
    }
    ],
  },
  methods: {
  foo(){
   console.log('row1val',this.rows[0].value);
    console.log('row2val',this.rows[0] ? this.rows[1].value : 'no row');
    console.log('row3val',this.rows[2] ? this.rows[2].value : 'no row');
  },
  addRow() {
      this.rows.push(
        {
          options:[
            {name:'Option 1',value:'opt1'},
            {name:'Option 2',value:'opt2'},
            {name:'Option 3',value:'opt3'},
            {name:'Option 4',value:'opt4'},
            {name:'Option 5',value:'opt5'}
          ],
          value:''
        }
      )
    },
    deleteRow(index) {
      console.log('Deleting index',index);
      this.rows.splice(index,1)
    },
    selectedOption(event, index) {
      this.rows[index].option = event.target.value;
      console.log("this.rows["+index+"].option: "+this.rows[index].option);
    },
    selectedRadio(event, index) {
      isSelected = true;
      console.log("isSelected("+index+"): "+ isSelected);
      if(isSelected){
                    this.isSelected = event.target.value;

            var name = event.target.getAttribute('name');
            var id = event.target.getAttribute('id');
            console.log(name, id);

            this.rows[index].selected = event.target.value;
            console.log("this.users["+index+"].selected: "+this.rows[index].selected);
        
      }
    }
 }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

<p>
  Rows: {{ rows.length }} 
  <button @click="addRow">Add Row</button>
  <button @click="foo">Debug</button>
</p>

 <br />
 <form @submit.prevent name="test">
 <template v-for="(row,rowNum) in rows">
   

 <button @click="deleteRow(rowNum)">Delete: &nbsp;{{ rowNum+1 }}&nbsp;</button>
 
 <template v-for="option in row.options">
  <input type="radio" :name="'row-'+rowNum" v-model="row.value" :value="option.value">{{option.name}}
</template>

  <select name="selects" @change="selectedOption($event,rowNum)">

<template v-for="index in 10">

<option :value="'test-'+index">Test {{ index }}</option> 

 
</template>

</select> <br />
 </template>

</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your eply and solution, but the issue is the posting as associative array in the form of option[] to a PHP/API through axios to iterate and do a bulk entry, where the solution you provided will not fit since it sends each radio/option as an indivudual array entry of its own.

Comment: Desired is as:
`Array
(
    [selects] => Array
        (
            [0] => test-1
            [1] => test-2
            [2] => test-3
            [3] => test-4
            [4] => test-5
        )

    [options] => Array
        (
            [0] => option5
        )`

Comment: while your solution gives this:

`Array
(
    [row-0] => opt1
    [selects] => Array
        (
            [0] => test-1
            [1] => test-2
            [2] => test-3
            [3] => test-4
            [4] => test-5
        )

    [row-1] => opt2
    [row-2] => opt3
    [row-3] => opt4
    [row-4] => opt5
`